# A question regarding Cauchy's convergence test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

The convergence test is this statement:

$ \forall \epsilon>0,\exists N>0:n>N,\forall p\in \mathbb N \implies |a_{n+p}-a_n|<\epsilon\iff \{a_n\}$ has a finite limit

This is the wrong version of it.

$ \forall \epsilon>0,\forall p\in \mathbb N, \exists N>0:n>N \implies |a_{n+p}-a_n|<\epsilon\iff \{a_n\}$ has a finite limit

Can this "wrong" statement prove $|\sqrt {n+p}-\sqrt{n}|<\epsilon$ when n is large enough?

My idea is that if using this wrong statement during the prove, things will be

$\displaystyle |\sqrt {n+p}-\sqrt{n}|=|\frac{p}{\sqrt {n+p}+\sqrt{n}}|=\frac{p}{\sqrt {n+p}+\sqrt{n}}$. Then based on the wrong statement, "for all $p\in \mathbb N$, there exists a N",I can regard $p$ as a constant at this time. Thus when n is sufficiently large, $\displaystyle \frac{p}{\sqrt {n+p}+\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon\implies |\sqrt {n+p}-\sqrt{n}|<\epsilon\implies \{\sqrt n\}$ has a finite limit. By using the wrong statement, the result can be this.

However, if using the right statement for the convergence test and going back to this step in the proof

$ \displaystyle \frac{p}{\sqrt {n+p}+\sqrt{n}}$. Then at this time, since in the right statement, $N$ is only depend on $\epsilon$, $p$ at this time is not a constant. Thus,I can't say when n is sufficiently large, $ \displaystyle \frac{p}{\sqrt {n+p}+\sqrt{n}}$ can smaller than $\epsilon,\forall \epsilon>0$, and the result will be $\{\sqrt{n}\}$ is not convergent to a finite number which is correct.

Comment: Second statement is same with $\forall p, \lim(\sqrt{n+p}-\sqrt{n})=0$ i.e. "non uniform" convergence for each $p$.

Comment: I have not learned uniform convergence this part yet, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one question in the Question, so I address it...

$ \underline{\forall \epsilon>0,\forall p\in \mathbb N}, \exists N>0:n>N \implies |a_{n+p}-a_n|<\epsilon\iff \{a_n\} \text{ has a finite limit}$

Let $\varepsilon$ and $p$ be given.  Example: $\varepsilon = 1/10$ and $p = 23$.  We now ask, does there exist a positive $N$ such that  $|\sqrt{n+p} - \sqrt{n}| < \varepsilon$ is true for all $n > N$?

Example: Since $n+23 > n > 0$, we start with the simplification $|\sqrt{n+23} - \sqrt{n}| = \sqrt{n+23} - \sqrt{n}$ to see if we obtain an inequality of the form "$n > {}$ some constant" (or a solution that is a union of intervals, at least one of which is of that form)...
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n+23} - \sqrt{n} &< \frac{1}{10}  \\
|n+23| - 2 \sqrt{n+23}\sqrt{n} + |n| &< \frac{1}{100}  \\
n + \frac{23}{2} - \sqrt{n^2+23n} &< \frac{1}{200}  \\
- \sqrt{n^2+23n} &< \frac{1}{200}  - n - \frac{23}{2} \\
\sqrt{n^2+23n} &> n + \frac{2299}{200}  \\
n^2+23n &> n^2 + \frac{2299n}{100} + \frac{5\,285\,401}{40\,000}  \\
23n -  \frac{2299n}{100} &> \frac{5\,285\,401}{40\,000}  \\
n &> \frac{5\,285\,401}{400}  \\
n &> 13\,213.5025  \text{.}
\end{align*}
So, if we set $N = 13\,213$ (or any larger number), then $n > N$ implies $|\sqrt{n+23} - \sqrt{n}| < 1/10$.

So let's repeat those manipulations for the general case.
Since $n+p \geq n > 0$, we start with the simplification $|\sqrt{n+p} - \sqrt{n}| = \sqrt{n+p} - \sqrt{n}$...
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n+p} - \sqrt{n} &< \varepsilon  \\
|n+p| - 2 \sqrt{n+p}\sqrt{n} + |n| &< \varepsilon^2  \\
n + \frac{p}{2} - \sqrt{n^2+pn} &< \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2  \\
- \sqrt{n^2+pn} &< \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2  - n - \frac{p}{2} \\
\sqrt{n^2+pn} &> n + \frac{p-\varepsilon^2}{2}  \\
n^2+pn &> n^2 + (p-\varepsilon^2)n + \frac{(p-\varepsilon^2)^2}{4}  \\
pn -  (p-\varepsilon^2)n &> \frac{(p-\varepsilon^2)^2}{4}  \\
\varepsilon^2n &> \frac{(p-\varepsilon^2)^2}{4}  \\
n &> \frac{(p-\varepsilon^2)^2}{4\varepsilon^2}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
So, if we set $N = \max\left\{1,\frac{(p-\varepsilon^2)^2}{4\varepsilon^2}\right\}$ (or any larger number), then $n > N$ implies $|\sqrt{n+p} - \sqrt{n}| < \varepsilon$.

Since a suitable choice of $N$ exists, the left-hand side of the biimplication in the wrong statement is true for $a_n = \sqrt{n}$.  That is, with that choice of $a_n$,
$$ \forall \epsilon>0,\forall p\in \mathbb N, \exists N>0:n>N \implies |a_{n+p}-a_n|<\epsilon $$
is true; and if we accept the biimplication, we conclude (wrongly) $\{\sqrt{n}\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ has a finite limit.

Comment: Thus, if using the wrong statement, the choice of N can depend on p, so there can be an answer of choosing N with the appearance of the letter p. However, in the right statement, the choice of N is independent of p, so the answer of suitable N can't have anything with the letter p. With this restriction, we can't have "n>" this expression if using the right one. Is this correct?

Comment: @Yink : Yes.  An object of existential quantification can depend on all the variables introduced externally to its quantified context.  For $N$ in the correct statement, $N$ can only depend on $\varepsilon$.  For $N$ in the wrong statement, $N$ can depend on both $\varepsilon$ and $p$ (since both are quantified in a scope that encloses $N$'s scope).